# How do I create a shortcut to the 32 bit ODBC administrator on deployment?

Tags: deployment, installation, odbc, windows-installer

I have a 32 bit application that will use different ODBC data sources.

To prevent confusion, I would like to create a shortcut in deployment that links to the 32 bit version of Windows ODBC Administrator.

What is the best way to do this?

Here's the hangups I see:

- The location is different on different versions of the OS.
- Windows XP x64 Media does not include the 32 bit ODBC database administrator.

The main problem is that Windows 7 x64 does not include any links to this tool.  If you want to run it, you have to go digging very deep.  And, to make things worse, users often run the x64 version of the tool, and get confused when they can not find their 32 bit drivers.

Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: I only have access to Win7 x64 at the moment, where it's at `%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`. Where is it on other versions?

Comment: Well, if if it's not a x64 install, there's no SysWOW64.  I don't really know.  I really only need to show this shortcut on x64 computers.  But, guess I just need to learn more about deployment.  I guess there should be a way to check to see if that file exist, and then create a shortcut.  That's all I really need to do.